# Out of body experience tests. How to contact scientists?

Tags: neuroscience, psychology

I am 30 year-old man with cerebral palsy. Somehow that and one antispastic drug (baclofen) turned me into a vivid dreamer and out of body experiencer. I am not a believer, quite the opposite because those "other realities" are terrifying, but I often floated in my room, and was also aware of this. Aware to the point that I managed to test a few things.

Sometimes I was floating, sometimes standing on my own legs and watching me sleep, sometimes even seeing me sleeping and me watching myself sleeping from sort of TPP (frequent gamer here, third person perspective)

I would really like to report my case for scientific research.  Does anyone know of a research group interested in a case report?

Comment: Although I’m not a researcher in this field, I’m interested in this phenomenon and have some interesting references about it. I’ll give you the links to some of the references I have so that you may try to contact the authors. They may be interested in meeting you or can give you advice or refer you to other researchers: [Ref 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3918960/#S5title),  [Ref 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165017305000792), and [Ref 3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079612305500244#!). Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Paranormal research is out of scope for this forum.  You can check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prizes_for_evidence_of_the_paranormal for some possibilities.  There is a standard test that you can run on yourself first though: It involves a random number generator that you can't see while sleeping - use a camera to record it, and when you wake up in the morning, compare what you saw in your sleep to what number the camera recorded at night.  Good luck!

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - I find over 3,000 studies in Pubmed on this topic, including some in PNAS, Cortex and Frontiers

Comment: @AliceD I see what you mean.  Do you think this question should be reopened?

Comment: Another thing you can try is a subject register.  These are usually country specific, such as [RegisterMatch](https://www.researchmatch.org/) for the USA; you'll need to see if your country has one.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I think it should, yes. It's not self-help and apparently there's research on it. But you seem to be the expert here, it's outside of my comfort zone, but a cursory search does indicate it's subject to scientific research

Comment: @AliceD My thinking is that as-is, although not self-help (strictly speaking), it is not very general - ie, I don't see how anyone else would benefit from it.  It could be edited to a more general "how do I find scientists interested in my mental health condition", in which case the condition itself is less relevant.  Krzysiek - do you want to try that instead?

Comment: I thought that the knowledge about connection of this phenomena to cerebral palsy and drugs would be beneficient to someone, also my knowledge about how memory works during those. I struggled to find these connections online, so I thought it is unknown. Perhaps I am mistaken and my knowledge is already known. I know it is not paranormal, just thought that my case was rare enough to be useful that's all

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg perhaps you're right. It's kind of borderline, a more generalized version would indeed be a big improvement

Comment: You see I don't want to be tested or anything. I just conducted these tests myself to know how memory works during these OOBE and what causes them. And I just wanted to check if knowledge like this is of any interest to anyone, because it was difficult for me to find the stuff I already know. But later I found out this IS known, so my knowledge is not as valuable as it seemeed at first, so sorry for all the fuss

Comment: it\s just that mine experiences were so often that I managed to test these internally, from the inside, like analysing my mental state while being inside my head so to speak. Thought that this POV may be useful to neuroscientists, perhaps mental health specialists. I already contacted one specialist about this. If he will be interested, then I will share. If nobody will be, then it means it is known and I wasted your time.,

Comment: It’s not a fuss at all. The out-of-body experience (OBE) is an interesting phenomenon. It can help us understand some of the functions of the brain and another related phenomenon – the near death experience – better.  Although the OBE phenomenon is being studied scientifically and we know that it is somehow related to functioning of the temporo-parietal areas, we still DON’T KNOW this phenomenon very well. I think if you kindly contribute your experiences to the study, you can help yourself and the scientific community understand it better. That will be valuable knowledge.

Comment: Should I put my findings somewhere over here? They were already in the first version of my post, but the post itself was too robust because of that. Maybe in the comment section for anyone to see and spread the news?

Comment: I already contacted the author of these works you sent me by the way, thanks

Comment: I do not have the proper expertise to truly publish my research, nor are they professional enough, just wanted to show them to someone, who may shape them into one, who may perform true research based on my experiences.

Comment: I don’t think this question forum is the place to report your findings. There may be some section on S.E. that you may appropriately post them, but I don’t know where. However, I don’t think doing that will be effective because few people here, if any, are researchers on OOBE. The best way is to try to contact researchers on OOBE as you’ve already done. Keep trying. I think someone will be interested in your case. If so, you will have the opportunity to talk with experts and even do research and jointly publish the findings with them. Again, I wish you the best of luck!